# Print image from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, printing

i have some images .... the size of each image is different 
For example:

```
img1 = 200 x 1900
img2 = 1800 x 400
img3 = 600 x 800
```

// HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src='img1.jpg'>    
    <img src='img2.jpg'>
    <img src='img3.jpg'>
</body>
</html>
```

// javascript

```
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            data = "<img src='img1.jpg'><img src='img2.jpg'><img src='img3.jpg'>";
            mywindow.document.write(data);  // data = all image
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
```

Now the output is all images printed but the sizes is corrupted 
how can i print each image in page A4 and print it fitted in page (A4)

Comment: what is `data` a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can define CSS rules for printing and base the dimensions on 21cm x 29.7cm.

For example :

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
   img {
      max-width: 18cm;
      max-height: 8cm;
   }
}
</style>
```

Note that if your page is simple enough, you don't have to build a new layout in a new window as you can simply define different rules for `@media print` and `@media screen`.

Comment: what about print each image in page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Websites are created for screens, not printers.

However you could force the web browser to display the page with the same pixel dimensions as A4. However, there may be a few quirks when things are rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body {
        height: 842px;
        width: 595px;
        /* to centre page on screen*/
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    </style>
  <head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The best solution for printing, is to use PDFs, that's what they are for. Create a PDF that has the same data. You have full control over the print format in that case.

Comment: what about print each image in page ?

Comment: but this dimensions will be different for different printers (different dpi) ... right ?

Comment: this current height/weight is for 72dpi, which i think is standard for most printers, and it also is scaled to fit A4 sheet