# Print button not print images but print text document

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use the following java script for print button.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printform()
    {
         var printContent = document.getElementById('<%= Panel1.ClientID %>');
         var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
         var uniqueName = new Date();
         var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
         var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');

         printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
         printWindow.document.close();
         printWindow.focus();
         printWindow.print();
         printWindow.close();
    }
 </script>
```

The above code not print the images but print text document.What can I do to solve the  problem.Plz provide me the solution.

Comment: images would be image tags or background images?

Comment: Look into print stylesheets, there is no reason to open a new window to print.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884575/print-image-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

In case if you find difficult to see the background images to get printed on document, make sure you have this option set in IE, if you use IE.

[image]